# Getting the percentage of points within an area

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst

I'm new to ArcGIS and trying to gather the number of points and a percentage of those points within a somewhat small area. How would I do this or what would this be called? Spatial query? I have attempted to find information on this but have been unsuccessful.

Comment: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000008599#:~:text=In%20the%20attribute%20table%20of,Count%20%3D%20%2C%20and%20click%20OK.

Answer (score 0):

To get the density of points per a user defined area use the Point Density tool in the Spatial Analyst toolbox.  You can find the documentation for the tool [here](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/point-density.htm).  To get the percentage of those points you could:

1. Open the attribute table and see how many records were in your feature class.
2. Then use the raster calculator to create a new raster layer with an expression like total_count/point_density_layer*100.  The resulting raster will be the percentage of points per user defined area.

Use caution and ensure you use the environment settings so your percentage raster outputs the same cell sizes and cell registration as your point density tool.

Your question asks multiple questions which violates the one-question policy. There are multiple steps that could each be their own question. Please take the GIS Stack Exchange tour to prevent your questions from being closed by site administrators in future posts.